# Have jQuery autoNumeric.js display the number of decimals different on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to configure the autoNumeric.js plugin to display the number of decimals different than the actual value?

So on blur it will display eg:

100.35

and on focus:

100.34578 (the real value of the input)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#target").blur(function() {
    $("#target").autoNumeric('init',{
        mRound : '/whatever round  you want when it is blured/'
    })
})

$("#target").focus(function() {
    $("#target").autoNumeric('init',{
        mRound : '/whatever round  you want when it is focused/'
    })
})
```

You can find the rounding options that autoNumeric has here:
[autoNumeric Documentation](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/#mRound)

Comment: That would be $("#target").autoNumeric('update' I guess. But that won't work because it would really change the value, so it would change to 100.34000 after blur and focus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - look at version 2.0 beta and the "eDec" option.

The default is 'null' but setting a number will extend the decimal place on focus

Example the default min/max has two decimal places and when you set {eDec: '5'} on focus this can extend to five.

Note the following:

- When using the "get" the extended value will be returned.
- The the extended value is stored as jQuery's data and attached to the element. Also look at the "aStore" option on preserving the data if the page looses focus.